# Dúvida Trazer Data Específica - Oracle

Tags: query, oracle

Na consulta abaixo está trazendo dessa forma.

```
Data Inicial      Data Final      Dia da Semana

16/10/18          30/10/2018           3
```

Onde esse data inicial e o data final é de um período específico e o dia da semana nesse caso é ***3 = Terça Feira***. Eu gostaria de saber se teria alguma consulta que pudesse trazer da forma abaixo.

Por exemplo, dentro desse período tem 3 terças feiras que são os dias.

```
16/10/2018
23/10/2018
30/10/2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma procedure e passe os valores por parametro p_data_ini e p_data_fim

```
select data from
(select to_date(:p_data_ini) + level - 1 data from dual 
connect by level <= (to_date(:p_data_fim) - to_date(:p_data_ini) + 1))
where to_char(to_date(data),'d') = 3
```